# SqlMetal Not Generating Views, Functions, or Stored Procedures

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-express, sqlmetal

I am using the following commands as part of a cmd file:

```
sqlmetal /server:localhost\SQLEXPRESS /database:DashBoard /dbml:DataClasses.dbml /namespace:DashBoard.Data
sqlmetal /server:localhost\SQLEXPRESS /database:DashBoard /views /functions /sprocs /code:DataClasses.designer.cs /context:DataClassesDataContext /namespace:DashBoard.Data DataClasses.dbml
```

Has anyone else had any problems generating the code to use views, functions, or stored procedures using SqlMetal?  The files are pointing to table references as expected, but the /views /functions and /sprocs switches seem to have no effect.

I am using SqlMetal 1.00.30729, SQL Server 2005 Express on my local machine, and the web app is ASP.NET 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to use the following commands instead:

```
sqlmetal /server:localhost\SQLEXPRESS /database:DashBoard /views /functions /sprocs /dbml:DataClasses.dbml /namespace:DashBoard.Data
sqlmetal /server:localhost\SQLEXPRESS /database:DashBoard /code:DataClasses.designer.cs /context:DataClassesDataContext /namespace:DashBoard.Data DataClasses.dbml
```